# Printing text from a Protractor repeater

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, protractor

I have the following e2e test that works fine:

```
            var results = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.
                     repeater('phone in phones').column('phone.name'));
            results.then(function(arr) {
             expect(arr.length).toEqual(2);
        });
```

Instead of the count/length, I want to have a test that checks for the text the results, something like:

```
expect(repeater('.phones li', 'Phone List').column('phone.name')).
      toEqual(["Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi",
               "MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122"]);
```

but using Protractor syntax, I tried the following but no go:

```
var results = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.
                 repeater('phone in phones').column('phone.name'));
        results.then(function(arr) {
         expect(arr.getText()).toEqual(....);
    });
```

but I'm getting a no method getText() error.
What is the way to get the text in the "arr" array?

This works:

```
            ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('phone in phones').column('phone.name'))
            .then(function(arr) {
                arr[0].getText().then(function(text) {
                    console.log("*** first: "+text);

                });
                arr[1].getText().then(function(text) {
                    console.log("*** second: "+text);

                    done();
                })
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the way your are chaining your methods. The element lookup is just bringing back the WebElement. What you are really after is the promise object that gets returned by getText(). If you want to do something with the text once the promise has resolved, you need to chain the 'then' call onto the end of the getText() call. So instead of:

```
results.then(function(arr) {
     expect(arr.getText()).toEqual(....);
});
```

you actually want something like this:

```
results.getText().then(function(resultText) {
     expect(resultText).toEqual(....);
})
```

Comment: the last edit I made works in a way, but it gets the whole row, not just "phone.name". So now I'm trying to figure out how to get only phone.name to show up in the arr[0].getText(), and not the whole row